# Splitting Sheets into Tabs

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, tabs

I have found a formula that helps me sort a master sheet into separate tabs (sorting by last name).  I was wondering if I can add an "or" to the formula in some way. I am sorting by last name but sometimes the person entering the data uses a capital and sometimes they don't. I would like to pull the last name (regardless of capitilization into the same tab (i.e. - Smith and smith would both go to the same tab).  Here is the formula I am using (but I can only figure out how to use either Smith or smith, not both. THanks for your help!

```
=query('Form Responses 1'!A:H,"Select * Where C='Smith")
```

Answer (score 0):

yes:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:H, "where C='Smith' or C='smith'")
```

but it's better to do it this way:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:H, "where C matches 'Smith|smith'")
```

or:

```
 =QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:H, "where lower(C) = 'smith'")
```

or:

```
=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A:H, "where C matches '(?i)smith'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
=Query('Form Responses 1'!A:H,"where C matches '[Ss]mith'")
```